# Vietnam Mathematical Olympiad 2024 - First Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions, programming

Problemset paper (in Vietnamese):
https://www.facebook.com/share/p/PpV3EQVE4chTZnZC/?mibextid=TrneLp

I am looking at the problem set of the VMO2024, but I can't solve any of them, nor have an idea of what to do =(. However, they look really interesting, and here is the first question:

> For all real numbers $x$, define $\lfloor x \rfloor$ as the largest integer not greater than x. Example $\lfloor \frac{9}{2} \rfloor = 4, \lfloor -2\rfloor = -2, \lfloor -341.4 \rfloor = -342 $.
>
> For integer $n \geq 1$, define two sequences $$\{ a_n \}_{n=1}^\infty = \frac{1}{4^{\lfloor -log_4n \rfloor}} \\ \{b_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty = \frac{1}{n^2} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k- \frac{1}{a_1 + a_2} \right)$$
>
> $a)$ Find a polynomial $P(x)$ with real coefficients such that $\forall n \geq 1: b_n = P\left( \frac{a_n}{n} \right)$
>
> b) Proof that there exists an (increasing) sequence $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} b_{n_k} = \frac{2024}{2025}$

My initial idea is to evaluate what some of the first $a_n, b_n$ are. Using the properties of the floor function: $$a_n = \frac{1}{4^{\lfloor -log_4 n \rfloor}} = \frac{1}{4^{-\lceil log_4  n \rceil}} = 4^{\lceil log_4 n \rceil}$$ or in other words, $$a_n = \text{Smallest power of 4 that is larger to equal to n}$$

If it helps, $\frac{1}{a_1 + a_2} = \frac{1}{5}$.

I wrote a [Python program to numerically evaluate a few first terms](https://gist.github.com/hoangminhduc0308/2b56293bf5b41280098c896f2b2524ca). If you want to see the values in a markdown-table style, change the value `st` in line $45$ from $0$ to $1$. Even with that, my head was still blank.

What do you think?

Comment: Active contest questions are not allowed on Math StackExchange.  If this is not an active contest question, provide source documentation showing the contest has concluded (e.g., website link or contest results).  Otherwise, this question will be locked.

Comment: @heropup As far as I know, the contest ended today.

Comment: @heropup LNT is right. The problems are publicly revealed right after the contest ends, and I'm not a contestant, but rather someone who thinks these problems are interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that

$$ [-\log_4 n] = -k \quad (k \geq 0) \iff n \in [ 4^{k-1}+1, 4^k]:= \{  4^{k-1}+1,...,  4^k\}, $$

then suppose $n \in [ 4^{m-1}+1, 4^m], m \geq 1 $

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = a_1 + \sum_{k =1}^{m-2} \sum_{j \in {[4^{k-1}+1,4^k]}}a_j + \sum_{j \in {[4^{m-1}+1,n]}}a_j =  1 + \frac{4}{5}(4^{2m-2} -1) + (n-4^{m-1})4^m. $$

Hence,

$$ b_n = \frac{4^m}{n} - \frac{4^{2m}}{5n^2} = \frac{a_n}{n} - \frac{1}{5}\frac{a^2_n}{n^2}. $$

So the polynomial you are looking for is $P(x) = x - x^2/5$.

For b) the hint is the dyadic numbers of the form $m/4^k, m \in \{0, ..., 4^k \}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. It seems like $b_n \neq P(\tfrac{a_n}{n})$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @Jan Since you mentioned, I have to double-check. $b_2 = (5-1/5)/2^2 = 6/5$, $a_2/2 = 4/ 2 = 2$ and so $P(2) = 2 - 4/5 = 6/5$. We can also check $b_3 = (5+4-1/5)/9 =44/45$, $a_3/3 = 4/3$ so $P(4/3) = 4/3 - 16/45 = 44/45$, so it's true for $n = 2,3$. Could you give a counter-example so I can double check again?

Comment: Oops, sorry for wasting your time! I used a program to verify your claim, but accidentally mistyped. You were right :)